# Show/Hide NavigationBar and Tab bar on tap Gesture in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to show/hide my **NavigationBar** and my **tab bar** when I tap on a View.

I have a background video that I would like to tap on and then the **Navigationbar** and the **tab bar** should disappear and if I tap on it again, the Navigationbar and the tabor should re-appear.

I currently cannot even hide the Navigationbar.

I use this code:

```
struct FirstView: View {
 
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                PlayerView()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                        print("tapped!")
                            self.navigationBarHidden(true)
                            self.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
                            self.edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .bottom])
                    }
    
                }
            }
                
                
            }
        }
```

Its basically this code that I'm trying to use:

```
             .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                    print("tapped!")
                        self.navigationBarHidden(true)
                        self.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
                        self.edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .bottom])
                }
```

The above code will print ***tapped!*** but it doesn't hide anything.

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have state in order to hide navigation bar, something like this

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @State private var hideNavigationBar = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                PlayerView()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                        print("tapped!")
                        self.hideNavigationBar.toggle()
                    }
                
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(hideNavigationBar)
            .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .bottom])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for some reason this only show/hides the Navigation bar! The tab bar doesn't show/hide!\